# Why can't I hide from the Dark Brotherhood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just joined the Dark Brotherhood on my current character, and I've noticed it seems I can't hide from any of them.  No matter what I do, the eye stays always open when one of them is in the room.  Even if I'm alone in the room with just one, and I'm sneaking behind them, I'm detected.  Even when I use an Invisibility spell or potion, I'm still detected.

Does the Dark Brotherhood have magic eyes in the back of their heads or something?

Note:  This is with a level 81 character.  The only sneak-enhancing equipment in use (if any) was a pair of boots I'd enchanted myself.  Can't remember the boost level.

Comment: I seem to be able to hide from them... I also found I can beat the snot out of em with out them doing anything... Mighty fine stress release to shift into a werewolf and send Cicero flying across the open room.

Comment: Maybe it is the dark mother watching you? :p

Answer (score 3):

All I can suggest is that you may need a higher sneaking skill or the like. This is just a quick video of me sneaking around 4 of the people in the dark brotherhood. I have about an 85 skill and I am wearing the Dark Brotherhood Armor which gives me a bit of a bonus to sneak as well.

NOTE: Some times when I view this embedded it splits the video in two. The original is not like that and at higher display resolutions it does not show up that way. If you see this, sorry, not sure what happened.

When I hit a light spot its easier for them to spot me, but when I am behind them I am clearly hidden.

Comment: I've got a level 81 character.  Skill level should not be an issue.

Comment: @Iszi He means your sneak skill level.

Comment: @Marcelo - Character level 81 *almost* guarantees all skills are 100.  Come to think, I wonder what's the least levels you can have and still be 81?  I've noticed that my character XP bar is half-full with all maxed skills.

Comment: @Iszi I will try and think of a few more things if I can, but my character I took that video with was only level 43 or so and did not have issues with always being seen. I was only seen when it made sense to be seen.

Comment: @James - Thanks.  I wonder if I may have stumbled upon a rare undocumented feature?

Comment: @Iszi You are right :p. I call mind block.